# Solr rest API for schema updates returns Method Not Allowed 405

Tags: rest, http, indexing, solr, lucene

I am working with Solr and we have the need to use Solr Rest API in order to modify/add/remove fields dynamically. 
I have changed the schemaFactory to be ManagedIndexSchemaFactory and commented out the default one (ClassicIndexSchemaFactory) in solrconfig.xml as follow:

```
<schemaFactory class="ManagedIndexSchemaFactory">
    <bool name="mutable">true</bool>
    <str name="managedSchemaResourceName">managed-schema</str>
</schemaFactory>
<!-- <schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>  -->
```

Therefore, I restarted Solr, and tried to send a POST request to add a new field:

> URL: 
>  http://localhost:8080/solr-webapp/mycollection/schema 
>   HEADERS:
>  Content-type:application/json 
>  BODY: 
>  {
>   "add-field":{
>        "name":"sell-by",
>        "type":"string",
>        "stored":true } }

But I get a Method Not Allowed (405) response, and I do not know exactly what else I should do.

Am I missing something in the Solr configuration?

Have you had any of these problems with Solr?

 How can I fix it and work with Solr REST API?

**EDIT**
However if I send a GET request to http://localhost:8080/solr-webapp/mycollection/schema it works fine and I can see the schema.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the log files on the server?

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar I think it was because I was using the version 4.10.3, while the schema API https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+API are available from 5.3 and 5.4 not sure if available for 5, the documentation sends me to 5.4 which is not released yet

Comment: @ClemensKlein-Robbenhaar do you know if it is possible to generate a .war file for solr 5.3+ ? if Yes, how? I tried to run the ant script to compile it , but I cannot find any .war file

Comment: seems the `*.war` created by 4.x versions is gone. If you run `ant server` you will get an unpacked webapp in the `server/solr-webapp/webapp` directory instead - seems you are expected to package it up by yourself if you want a `*.war` file

Comment: yes, I am doing that, I ran the ant build from the source code, but I found also that exploded folder in the stand alone distribution, and then I created the /war file from the distribution, but I haven't checked yet if the APIs work. Still in the configuration process from 4.10.3 to 5.3.1